# how to remove unwanted mirror effect in a particular part

Tags: mirror

Dear all I am drawing a 3d image, and while drawing the face of the character I used mirror effect. But as the body of the character is not similar how can I remove it

Comment: By drawing do you mean sculpting?

Comment: hello, your question is a bit too vague, please show some screenshots